# Need help achieving HAProxy active/passive configuration for mysql

Tags: mysql, high-availability

I'm using HAProxy for mysql database backends. The database had to be master-slave. The goal is to point all mysql clients at the proxy and for all requests to go to mysql server #1 and only go to mysql server #2 if #1 is down.

There is an understanding and acceptance that when we are failed over to node 2, the database will be read only.

One thing I tried was setting the weight of node 1 to 256 and this kind of works but I don't want one out of 256 database calls going to node2; I need all calls to get directed to node1 unless node1 is actually down.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use the check backup option to second backend node in the conf file like so:

listen mysql-cluster
    bind 0.0.0.0:3306
    mode tcp
    option mysql-check user haproxy_check
    balance roundrobin
    server mysql-1 10.51.120.28:3306 check
    server mysql-2 10.51.123.25:3306 check backup